# How do I load an png image on unity3d and use a loading scene

Tags: css, unity-game-engine, load, unityscript, scene

I am making a loading scene . I am not using a loading bar . I going to use a png image . The script I have is for loading png image . I don't have any errors . The png is already imported in the project. Here is what I got for code :

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using UnityEngine.UI;
public class djsi : MonoBehaviour {
public  png;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
     img.gameObject.SetActive(false);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame

    IEnumerator abc()
 {
     img.gameObject.SetActive(true);
     yield return new WaitForSeconds(1.5f);
     SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync("scene1");
 }


    void Update () {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So from what I understand you want a static image as your loading screen, in which case this should give you an idea of what you will need to do, keep in mind this script needs to be attached to a UI Image object to work.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using UnityEngine.UI;
public class djsi : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Sprite png;
    Image Comp;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        Comp = gameObject.GetComponent<Image>();
        Comp.sprite = png;
        Comp.enabled = false;
        StartCoroutine(LoadScene());
    }

    // Update is called once per frame

    IEnumerator LoadScene()
    {
        Comp.enabled = true;
        SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync("scene1");
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1.5f);
        Comp.enabled = false;
    }


    void Update()
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: I didn't work . How would I make a  loading a scene I just have some text and background different color ?

Comment: @Freddy I tested the script so it should've worked, did you attach it to a UI text and then drag and drop a sprite in the inspector where it says "png"?

Comment: Yes and nothing happen.  I can do a basic loading scene for now. I have the text set up I just need the scene to switch over to the next scene but late like 2.5f . How do I code that ?

Comment: I got the scene reading code ready. But the problem is it switching scenes too fast .